# My DVD RW isn't visible when connected with two more sata devices

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, motherboard, sata, dvd

I used to install a HDD and DVD on my [Gigabyte G41 Motherboard](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-G41MT-ES2L-rev-13#ov) using two SATA connectors, few days ago I added a new SSD to my PC and connected it to my motherboard (Now 3 devices connected), but now my ASUS DVD-RW isn't visible in Windows Explore or even in the Device Manager!!!

I tried another additional SSD instead of the DVD and all the three devices are visible, so what is the problem of the DVD?

PS: when I remove one of the connected Disk Drives (Leave only 2 devices) the DVD works correctly..

What am I missing?

Note: I'm using Windows 10 1809 latest build.

EDIT: I found my DVD when ticking "Show hidden devices" from Device Manager:

[image]

And has an error in **Device status**:

[image]

Comment: First, update your BIOS and firmware.  You can also try powering down, then swapping around the power and sata cables. There's a chance not enough power is being delivered, or that one of the sata ports is malfunctioning.  You may have to change the boot device in BIOS (note which SATA port your boot drive is plugged into).

Comment: @ChristopherHostage
BIOS is at latest version, already swapped sata and the DVD is working correctly at boot time and reading bootable CDs but in Windows not